# "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" Errors in Testing Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript

In writing tests for my Angular 2 app, I am running into these errors: the selectors we're using:

```
"): AppComponent@12:35 'tab-view' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-tab' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    </div>
    <div class="app-body">
        [ERROR ->]<tab-view class="my-tab" [options]="tabOptions"></tab-view>
    </div> </div>
```

I have added [`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA) to my root module, as well as all other modules, but I am still getting the errors.

- What else do I need to do?
- Does this need to be in all modules, or just the root?
- Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: In all the modules where you have a component with a selector that contains a "-".

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, I've already done that. I've added this to all my modules. Still getting the errors.

Comment: you added the schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] to your TestBed.configureTestingModule?

Comment: I don't believe I have that module. Do I need to have it?

Comment: Yes, here you have it: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html
Also check the docs related to Testing with ngModules: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#testbed

Comment: In the end, defining that in my app.component.spec.ts file go it to work. Thanks for the help, Camaron.

Comment: I got my answer here but I'm confused now. Which approach is the best. The one which is accepted as answer or the one given at the bottom by Aryashree Pritikrishna.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So what I had to do to get this working was also set the schemas in the TestBed.configureTestingModule - which is not a separate module file, but a part of the app.component.spec.ts file. Thanks to [@camaron](http://@camaron) for the tip. I do think the docs could be a clearer on this point.

Anyway, this is what I added to get it to work. Here are the opening contents of my app.component.spec.ts file.

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './../app.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me... 3 years later ;)

Answer (score 6):

It works for me this way, in your spec.ts file you have to `import` your components and needs to add it to `declarations`. In my case its in about.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './../sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './../footer/footer.component';

describe('AboutComponent', () => {
  let component: AboutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AboutComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [ AboutComponent, SidebarComponent, FooterComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```