# Angular2 CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA Doesn't Work

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have just installed a bearbones ng2 app using the ng2 cli. In my `AppModule` I added `schema: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]`, and in my `AppComponent` template I have `<row></row>`. But I'm getting-

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'row' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'row' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'row' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

AppModule-

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppComponent-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

AppComponentTemplate-

```
<row></row>
```

It's really that simple. What the heck is going on?

**Edit:**

All of the answers below are satisfactory and provide insight into the problem. @yurzui I especially like your answer for providing the source. I wish I could give you all the accepted answer! But I will choose @camaron for being the first and giving the direct solution to my problem. If you find this question via google please give @yurzui, @camaron, and @Aravind a +1 for helping with this issue!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the `RowComponent` to be imported by your `AppModule`

`imports: [RowComponent]`

Edit:

Use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`, this is because angular is trying to find an component that doesn't exists.

`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` is for components with a `-` in the selector name.

Comment: I don't have a `RowComponent`, that is the problem. It is not intended to be a component, it's just a random element name.

Comment: try with NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA as last resource

Comment: Yeah that works. I wish I knew why CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA doesn't work. If no one can answer that question I will choose this as the answer

Comment: @MicahWilliamson I have edited the answer to cover your doubt about the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 7):

If you take a look at changelog https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc5-2016-08-09

> By default, Angular will error during parsing on unknown properties,
>   even **if they are on elements with a - in their name** **(aka custom**
>   **elements)**. If you application is using custom elements, fill the new
>   parameter @NgModule.schemas with the value [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA].

then you can understand that you need to have tag with `-` delimiter

```
if (tagName.indexOf('-') > -1) {
      if (tagName === 'ng-container' || tagName === 'ng-content') {
        return false;
      }

      if (schemaMetas.some((schema) => schema.name === CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA.name)) {
        // Can't tell now as we don't know which properties a custom element will get
        // once it is instantiated
        return true;
      }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.ts#L290

so something like `my-row` should work

Comment: I really appreciate the link to the source! +1

Answer (score 4):

The following are your mistakes

1. You have imported only **AppComponent** but it does not have any element with `<row>` as its template.
2. **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** need not be used during application development as it is used to hide errors that are caused occurs when templates are being parsed (as said in your error description).
3. `<app-root>` is the selector for your AppComponent, but you have used `<row>` in your html of the AppComponent.

Based on your requirement, I can suggest with various fixes. Comment with your desired outcome and I shall update answer based on them.

Comment: [in the tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) using the app-heroes component will result in this same error. how do i get around that? i want to use `<app-heroes/>` in my templates. [this may be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48025652/823282) the answer i was looking for.